# Saving to NSUserDefaults crashes app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a session to NSUserDefaults with the code below, and for some reason doing so is crashing my app with the following error.

> 2015-10-31 12:38:22.327 App[13930:4844726] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt
>   to insert non-property list object {type = immutable dict, count = 17, entries =>  0 :
>   status = 1    1 : theme = {contents
>   = ""}     2 : roles = {type = immutable dict, count = 2, entries =>    0 : 2 = {contents = "authenticated user"}   1 : 3 = {contents = "administrator"} }
>
> 3 : uid = 1     5 : access = {contents = "1446319867"}   6 : login = {value = +1446320300, type =
>   kCFNumberSInt64Type}  7 : picture = 
>     9 : {contents =
>   "signature_format"} =   10 : init =
>   {contents =
>   "brittany@email.ca"}  13 : signature = {contents = ""}     14 : data = {value = false}     15 : language = {contents = ""}     16 : created = {contents = "1428187324"}   17 : {contents = "rdf_mapping"} = {type = immutable dict, count = 3, entries =>   0 :
>   rdftype = {type = immutable, count
>   = 1, values = (   0 : {contents = "sioc:UserAccount"} )}  1 : name = {type = immutable dict, count = 1, entries =>   2 :
>   predicates = {type = immutable,
>   count = 1, values = (     0 : {contents = "foaf:name"} )} }
>
> 2 : homepage = {type =
>   immutable dict, count = 2, entries =>     0 : type = rel  2 : predicates
>   = {type = immutable, count = 1, values = (     0 : {contents =
>   "foaf:page"} )} }
>
> }
>
> 18 : timezone = {contents =
>   "America/Los_Angeles"}    21 : name = admin   22 : mail = {contents = "email@email.ca"} } 
>   for key diosSession'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x183db8f5c 0x1989aff80 0x183db8ea4 0x183df5970 0x183d427c0 0x183d416d8 0x183df5c74 0x183df520c
>   0x183df8a1c 0x184c21138 0x1000ef5c8 0x1000f14fc 0x100120850
>   0x1000e8248 0x10026dd70 0x10026dd30 0x100273780 0x183d70258
>   0x183d6e0c0 0x183c9cdc0 0x18edf0088 0x189376f44 0x100159674
>   0x1991da8b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

Any idea why?

Thanks!

```
[DIOSUser userLoginWithUsername:_userField.text
                  andPassword:_passField.text
                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
          // Saving to keychain/NSUserDefaults


          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]
                                                                                  forKey:@"diosSession"];
                                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                        [[DIOSSession sharedSession] getCSRFTokenWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                            NSString *csrfToken = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]];
                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:csrfToken forKey:@"diosToken"];
                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            // failure handler
                                        }];

                                        wrongLogin.hidden = YES;
                                        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                        MyAccountViewController *yourViewController = (MyAccountViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAccount"];
                                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

                                        [self.activityIndicatorViewOne stopAnimating];
                                        self.activityIndicatorViewOne.hidden = YES;

                                        NSLog(@"Success!");}

                                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { NSLog(@"Fail!"); wrongLogin.hidden = NO; }
             ];

        }
```

Comment: The types which can be stored in `NSUserDefaults` are restricted to property list complaint types (`NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSData` plus `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`containing the four types). The error message reveals that `[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]` does not conform to those types.

Comment: @Vadian Is there a way for me to make [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] compliant? Currently, that line returns an array of information. E.g. username, first name, last name, etc. Apologies for the newb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Any idea why?".  Yes:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]
                                          forKey:@"diosSession"];
```

I don't know what `[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]` is, but only a `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSNumber` and `NSDate` may be stored.

So I guess that's why.

Comment: ...`Boolean` feels left out :(

Comment: Not at all; it's stored in an `NSNumber` object.

Comment: It's the same for both iOS and OSX.  I don't follow your thinking?

Comment: It show's up as `Boolean` (YES/NO) when I view the `.plist` — that was my thinking. https://i.imgur.com/craKOtk.png

Comment: Boolean wrapped in a nsnumber object.

Comment: Yeah well that's good point.  If you stick `YES` into an `NSNumber` it's written to the property list as a `<bool>` as does `<real>` and `<integer>`, so I am thinking that `NSNumber` remembers the type used to initialise it (which I'm guessing is accessible from the `objCType` method).  This then must be used to write the correct type to the `.plist` file.

Comment: And the other objects you set?

Answer (score 0):

please try to this

for set the object :

```
NSData *yourData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourData forKey:@"yourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

for get the object :

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
    DIOSSession *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```